# find all subgroups of G where: $0 \ne r \in \Re$ $G = <r>$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, real-numbers

I need to find all subgroups of G where:

$G \lt \Re$

$0 \ne r \in \Re$

$G = <r>$

$\Re$ is the group of real numbers and G is a subgroup.

Edit :

the operation is +

I tried thinking about the devisors of r to be the presentations of the the subgroups. but $ r \in R$.. and that confused me

any help will be very appreciated.

thanks

Comment: The set of real numbers with the product is not a group.

Comment: thanks. so i thought to start thinking about the devisors of r . but $r \in R$ so it is a bit confusing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation is $+$ because $\mathbb{R}$ is not a group with $*$ ($0$ doesn't have inverse). If you fix a nonzero element $r$ then $$G = \langle r \rangle = \{ nr : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$This is infinite cyclic group, which means that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. So the final answer is just $\langle \mathbb Z, + \rangle$ and $0$.

> EDIT: $\langle \mathbb Z, + \rangle $ is isomorphic to $\langle r \rangle$ by the isomorphism $g : \mathbb Z \rightarrow \langle r \rangle$ ($\mathbb Z \ni x \mapsto xr$).
>   Moreover every $0 \neq H \leq \langle \mathbb Z, + \rangle$ is isomrphic to $\langle \mathbb Z, + \rangle$ itself by the isomorphism $f : \mathbb Z \rightarrow H$, defined as $\mathbb Z \ni x \mapsto mx$, where $m$ is the samllest positive integer contained in $H$. Now if you want to represent $H$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$ you only have to determine it's image under $g \circ f^{-1}$. If $mx \in H$, then $g \circ f^{-1}(mx) = g(f^{-1}(mx)) = g(x) = rx$. So that's for the non trivial subgroups. The trivial one maps to $\{0\}$, of course.

Comment: tnx. I don't get how Z can be a subgroup of that. if for example r = pi. how come Z is a subgroup of <pi>?

Comment: Oh, when people are talking about groups they in most cases make don't make difference between isomorphic groups. That's why I said that the answer is just $\mathbb{Z}$. But you are right as sets $\mathbb{Z} \neq <\pi>$, even though they are isomorphic as groups, which means that in algebraic sense they are the same thing.

Comment: Look at the above equation $G = \{n r : n\in \mathbb Z\}$. Think about how you might write an isomorphism $\phi : G\to \mathbb Z$, and check it's an isomorphism. Then if you believe they are isomorphic, do you know what all subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ are? How do these subgroups look in $G$?

Comment: tnx . so I know it is isomorphic to Z . and I think subgroups of Z with + are  i + nZ  where i between 0 to n-1 ?  I don't know how do they look in G and how I conclude that the answer is Z. thanks a lot again

Comment: OK, @user2993422 I'll explain it more precisely in my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! i have a much better understanding now